# SQL Server: Select Parent-Child

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data, recursive-cte

I have **SQL Server 2008** with a table called **ProductCategories** designed like this:

```
Id | Name      | ParentId
71   PCs         NULL
32   MACs        NULL
 3   Keyboard    1
 9   Mouse       1
 5   Screen      1
11   Keyboard    2
 7   Mouse       2
 8   Screen      2
```

I would like to select from this table, and get a result set like this:

```
Id | Name      | ParentId
71   PCs         NULL
 3   Keyboard    1
 9   Mouse       1
 5   Screen      1
32   MACs        NULL
11   Keyboard    2
 7   Mouse       2
 8   Screen      2
```

I tried this, but that obviously gives me the ones with no ParentId first:

```
WITH Hierarchy
AS
(
    SELECT 
        T1.Id, T1.ParentId
    FROM
        ProductCategories T1
    WHERE 
        T1.parentid IS NULL OR 
        T1.parentid IN (SELECT id from ProductCategories WHERE parentid IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        T1.Id, T1.ParentId
    FROM
        ProductCategories T1
    INNER JOIN 
        Hierarchy TH ON TH.Id = T1.ParentId
)
select *
from Hierarchy 
order by parentid
```

Please help me, if you can :)

--
*The guy who doesn't know SQL*

Comment: What (in english) are you trying to do ?  I can't reverse engineer your intent from the output you included. There are an infinite number of ways to generate that output from the data, but probably very few that would generate the "right" output (that does what you want) from a different sdet of data...

Comment: How does your result set differ from the raw data in the table, other than an undocumented sort order?

Comment: To clear this up: this table is referring to itself? Yep, apparently it does.

Comment: ahh I see it now, the values in the third column should be 71 and 32, not 1 & 2

Comment: @Charles: Yes, you got it. Your answer was spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
Select Id, Name, ParentId
From ProductCategories
Order By Coalesce(ParentId, Id), 
   Coalesce(ParentId, 0), Name
```

Three Order By predicates,

1. Coalesce(ParentId, Id): This one groups the records by the parent, for both the parent itself and all the children of that parent
2. Coalesce(ParentId, 0) This groups within each set so that the one record with a null parent (the parent) sorts to the top within the group
3. Name, This sorts the children within the group by name

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, name, parentId 
FROM categories
ORDER BY ISNULL(parentId,id), id
```

Btw, shouldn't first two indexes in your table be 1 and 2, not 71 and 32 ?

Comment: No. You can add and delete categories, and later on promote a new category to a parent category. So that would be the case with 71 and 32.